# MS Visual Studio 2019: how to find actual definition of a structure after preprocessing?

Tags: visual-c++, macros, structure, c-preprocessor

Not very familiar to Visual Studio ecosystem (My native environment/language is Delphi), though, as I intensively work with Ghostscript code I have to regularly face such structure definitions (no need for deciphering, just a hideous example):

```
#define gs_bitmap_common(data_type)                                         \
    data_type *     data;       /* pointer to the data */                   \
    int             raster;     /* increment between scanlines, bytes */    \
    gs_int_point    size;       /* width and height */                      \
    gs_bitmap_id    id      /* usually unused */

/* ... */

#define gs_tile_bitmap_common(data_type)                          \
    gs_bitmap_common(data_type);                                  \
    ushort      rep_width, rep_height   /* true size of tile */

/* ... */

#define gx_tile_bitmap_common(data_type) gs_tile_bitmap_common(data_type)

/* ... */

#define gx_strip_bitmap_common(data_type)\
        gx_tile_bitmap_common(data_type);\
        ushort rep_shift;\
        ushort shift;\
        int num_planes

/* ... */

typedef struct gx_strip_bitmap_s {
    gx_strip_bitmap_common(byte);
} gx_strip_bitmap;
```

This laborious definition is actually equivalent to the following one (and the preprocessor knows it!):

```
typedef struct gx_strip_bitmap_s {
        byte*           data;       /* pointer to the data */                   
        int             raster;     /* increment between scanlines, bytes */    
        gs_int_point    size;       /* width and height */                      
        gs_bitmap_id    id;     /* usually unused */
        ushort          rep_width, rep_height   /* true size of tile */
        ushort          rep_shift;
        ushort          shift;
        int             num_planes;
} gx_strip_bitmap;
```

Well, is there az easy way to find out (thru the VS interface) directly the actual definition of a structure after building (that is, after letting preprocessor do the work) without effectively starting the application? If wasn’t possible it would be a real shame – as the preprocessor just have done it for me.

(Looking thru the raw output of the preprocessor is quite uncomfortable, thus just a barely acceptable solution for huge projects with thousands of modules, like Ghostscript.)

Comment: `Looking thru the raw output of the preprocessor is quite uncomfortable` I take this to mean you are looking for something friendlier than `cl /P /Fi` or the "*preprocess to file*" option in the IDE. A quick search found the [DevUtils](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Trass3r.DevUtils) extension that "*adds items to the editor context menu for inspecting the preprocessor and code generator output for C++ [...]*" though I don't have any first hand experience with it.

Comment: Your answer would be otherwise excellent but unfortunately DevUtils doesn’t work for MakeFile projects, like GhostScript.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. That's unfortunate, though maybe not entirely surprising.